# display date on page

Tags: php, mysql, date

my date format from my db was Y-m-d h:i:s sample: 2017-08-30 19:19:20 and im trying to display that date on my page..

but the problem is when it displays on my page the date was different compared to the data from my db..

like 
data from db was

```
2017-08-21  18:00:00
2017-08-24  18:00:00
2017-08-30  18:00:00
```

but the date that was being displayed was

```
12/31/1969 6:00 PM
12/31/1969 6:00 PM
12/31/1969 6:00 PM
```

this is the format that i use..

```
<?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i a',strtotime($date)); ?>
```

$date is the date from my db..

```
the date should be 
08/21/2017 6:00 PM
08/24/2017 6:00 PM
08/30/2017 6:00 PM
```

any idea why this happens and any possible solution for this?..

Comment: are you sure you are getting dates from your database? If you are not getting dates from database you will get dates like you have mentioned in your question

Comment: try to look in your db and debug it because you may be overriding variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given lines of php code should be able to give the required output :-

```
<?php

$dates = [
'2017-08-21  18:00:00',
'2017-08-24  18:00:00',
'2017-08-30  18:00:00',
];

foreach ($dates as $string) {
    $date = new DateTime($string);
    echo $date->format('m/d/Y g:i A')."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
08/21/2017 6:00 PM
08/24/2017 6:00 PM 
08/30/2017 6:00 PM
```

The code snippet is taken from the [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EQHF9).

Comment: For OP desired output: `echo $date->format('m/d/Y g:i A')`

Comment: the dates are not in array.. i just display the sample dates.. but im not getting it in array..

Comment: I know. But the logic is still the same, loop or not.

Comment: Just get rid of the loop then, I only looped so I could show you it working three times with each date you supplied.

Comment: i tried it but the date that is being displayed was the current date not the date from my db.. like what you said i just get rid of the loop

Comment: Did you pass in the date string? If it's today's date then it sounds like you didn't?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seems to answer how to fix it.
I thought I could explain why it happens.

Strtotime fails because it can't parse the date and returns false.
False is the same as 0.
This zero is taken by date and creates a date according to your format.
But because strtotime returned 0 the date returns 0 UNIX time => 1970-01-01 00:00.
And since you are in a timezone (or server at least) with negative difference to UTC a few hours are subtracted from 1970-01-01 00:00 and that leaves you with your output.